# Data Structure to Find Next Greatest Value Below Arbitrary Number

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm trying to find a data structure to use in my Java project. What I'm trying to do is get the next greatest value below an arbitrary number from a set of numbers, or be notified if no such number exists.

Example 1)
My Arbitrary number is 7.0.
{3.1, 6.0, 7.13131313, 8.0}
The number I'd need to get from this set would be 6.0.

Example 2)
My arbitrary number is 1.0.
{2.0, 3.5555, 999.0}
A next highest number doesn't exist in the set, so I'd need to know it doesn't exist.

The best I can think of is indexing and comparing through an array, and going back 1 step once I go over my arbitrary number. In worst case scenarios though my time complexity would be O(n). Is there a better way?

Comment: why not use binary search?

Comment: Maintain a search tree, and if it doesn't have it, implement a predecessor function.

Answer (score 4):

If you can pre-process the list of values, then you can sort the list (`O(NLogN)` time) and perform a binary search which will take `O(LogN)` for each value you want to get an answer for. otherwise you can't do better than `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the numbers at first.
And then you could do a simple binary search whose compare function modified to your need. At every point check the element is bigger than input, if so search in the left side or in the right side. Your modified binary search, at the end should be able to provide the immediate bigger and the smaller number with which you could solve your problem easily. Complexity is lg n.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look at either [`TreeSet.floor(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#floor%28E%29) or [`TreeSet.lower(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#lower%28E%29).  One of those should satisfy your requirements, and both have `O(logN)` complexity ... assuming that you have already built the `TreeSet` instance.

If you only have a sorted array and don't want the overhead of building a `TreeSet`, then a custom binary search is the probably the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Your both example sets look sorted ...

If it is the case then you would need a binary search...
If it's not the case then you would need to visit every elements exactly one time.so it would take time n..